# The home directory does not exist or is missing the run.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380754/cannot-find-java-ee-packages-in-eclipse-for-java-ee#comment11849761_9380754) about this earlier and was told to restate the question to be a bit more specific.

My problem is that my Eclipse cannot recognize Java EE's `javax.servlet` packages. I have viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project) about fixing the problem but get stuck where I am supposed to go through the new server wizard. I click on *New>Server* and select JBoss 5.1, which is the version I have installed, but I get an error message stating

> The home directory does not exist or is missing the run.jar

How can I integrate JBoss 5.1 in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can have at least the following causes:

1. JBoss is not properly installed. Make sure that the zip is fully extracted.
2. Home directory is not properly selected. Make sure that it points to root of JBoss installation folder.
3. The JBoss tools plugin is either outdated or buggy. Try the latest version matching your Eclipse version.